# Difference between model training in PyTorch and libTorch

Tags: c++, libtorch

I was trying to train a model in C++ API (libtorch) and got bad results. I then compared in a detailed way to pytorch. My network is very simple (linear with 4 inputs and outputs and only one hidden layer). In order to compare I set all in sequential in the dataloader (on both sides : shuffle=False in python and SequentialSampler for the dataloader in API), the same random seed, same batch size and learning rate, same optimizer (SGD), same loss function. And the results were still bad in API and good in python.

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title. Either post your solution below to help others with the same problem (and press the checkmark next to it to mark the question as solved), or delete the question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posting answer on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space).*

I finally found that in torch API the mse_loss reduction is set by default to mean, which seems to be much less efficient than what is common in python (reduction='sum'). This is done through:

```
namespace F = torch::nn::functional;
auto loss = F::mse_loss(output, target, F::MSELossFuncOptions(torch::kSum));
```